# Create a master data set comprised of multiple data frames

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now! Included below is a very simplified version of my program, along with some context. Essentially I want to view is one large dataframe which has all of my desired permutations based on my input variables. This is in the context of scenario analysis and it will help me avoid doing on-demand calculations through my BI tool when the user wants to change variables to visualise the output.

I have tried:

1. Creating a function out of my code and trying to apply the function with each of the step size changes of my input variables ( no idea what I am doing there).
2. Literally manually changing the input variables myself (as a noob I realise this is not the way to go but had to first see my code was working to append df's).

Essentially what I want to achieve is as follows:

1. use the variables "date_offset" and "cost" and vary each of them by the required number of defined steps sizes and number of steps
2. As an example, if there are 2 values for date_offset (step size 1) and two values for cost (step size one) there are a possible 4 combinations, therefore the data set will be 4 times the size of the df in my code below.
3. Now I have all of the permutations of the input variable and the corresponding data frame to go with each of those permutations, I would like to append each one of the data frames together.
4. I should be left with one data frame for all of the possible scenarios which I can then visualise with a BI tool.

I hope you guys can help :)

Here is my code.....

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#want to iterate through starting at a date_offset of 0 with a total of 5 steps and a step size of 1
date_offset = 0
steps_1 = 5
stepsize_1 = 1

#want to iterate though starting at a cost of 5 with a total number  of steps of 5 and a step size of 1
cost = 5
steps_2 = 4
step_size = 1

df = {'id':['1a', '2a', '3a', '4a'],'run_life':[10,20,30,40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df['date_offset'] = date_offset
df['cost'] = cost
df['calc_col1'] = df['run_life']*cost
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want to create a dataset that has all the possible combinations of `date_offset` and `cost`, for all values of `run_life`? Or rather it looks like you want the paired up values of `date_offset` and `cost` and add those as columns to the dataframe? I think you're complicating something that's really quite simple in `pandas`, but you should be a bit more clear and straightforward about the result you're expecting. (why should `cost` and `date_offset` have 5 values, when `run_life` only has 4?)

Comment: I am wanting to create a dataset that has all possible combinations of of date_offset and cost, for all values of run_life. So 5 values of date_offset and 4 of cost would be 20 combinations. To answer you second question, I would also like to keep columns in the dataframes for reference. Runlife only has 4 because that is the number of rows for each datafame I would like to create. The real program has multiple columns that are depended on the stated input variables. I figured date_offset and cost would need to be a nested loop to iterate through to create each df. Hopefully this is clearer?

Comment: Your explanations are pretty vague: Could you add some expected output for your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
from itertools import product

data = {'id': ['1a', '2a', '3a', '4a'], 'run_life': [10, 20, 30, 40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

date_offset = 0
steps_1 = 5
stepsize_1 = 1

cost = 5
steps_2 = 4
stepsize_2 = 1

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    product(
        range(date_offset, date_offset + steps_1 * stepsize_1 + 1, stepsize_1),
        range(cost, cost + steps_2 * stepsize_2 + 1, stepsize_2)
    ),
    columns=['offset', 'cost']
)
result = df.merge(df2, how='cross')
result['calc_col1'] = result['run_life'] * result['cost']
```

Output:

```
     id  run_life  offset  cost  calc_col1
0    1a        10       0     5         50
1    1a        10       0     6         60
2    1a        10       0     7         70
3    1a        10       0     8         80
4    1a        10       0     9         90
..   ..       ...     ...   ...        ...
115  4a        40       5     5        200
116  4a        40       5     6        240
117  4a        40       5     7        280
118  4a        40       5     8        320
119  4a        40       5     9        360

[120 rows x 5 columns]
```